# Error php export to PDF when use mpdf

Tags: php, mpdf

I use mpdf (http://mpdf1.com/) to generate 1 pdf file

```
<?php
$html = '... the body of the document encoded in UTF-8 is 收到的货品如有任 ...';

$mpdf=new mPDF();
$mpdf->allow_charset_conversion = true;
$mpdf->charset_in = 'utf-8';
$mpdf->WriteHTML($html);

$mpdf->Output();

?>
```

Result `"... the body of the document encoded in UTF-8 is [][][][][][][][][] ...'"`, How to fix it?

Comment: can you var_dump(mb_detect_encoding ($html));

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try adding these :

```
$mpdf->useAdobeCJK = true;
$mpdf->autoScriptToLang = true;
$mpdf->autoLangToFont = true;
```

Check if it is working.

Comment: you to add those language to your library ,it requires the Adobe Asian Font pack.Check the detail here http://www.mpdf1.com/mpdf/index.php?page=Examples